Panda's Date Range Function
I am using a local file that contains employee data. I want to use TimeFrame to filter specific columns for the date ranges given. Rather than manually updating my 4 date ranges for .between(), how can I make a function or variable that I can just make it something like:
date = ("6/1/2023, 6/30/2023") and then have it .between(date).
I feel like this is simple but I'm doing something wrong so it keeps giving me errors.
TimeFrame = (WFRL["EOD (HIRE_DT)"].between("6/1/2023", "6/30/2023") |
            WFRL["Grade Entry Date"].between("6/1/2023", "6/30/2023") |
            WFRL["Step Date"].between("6/1/2023", "6/30/2023") |
            WFRL["WGI Due Dt"].between("6/1/2024", "6/30/2024"))

I'm make some type of basic error as different attempts aren't working.

Please avoid using screenshots and paste your code instead. Thank you

Images of data/code are not acceptable, provide a [mre]

How about this?
import pandas as pd

# Mock data.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "EOD (HIRE_DT)": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="today"),
        "Grade Entry Date": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="today"),
        "Step Date": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="today"),
        "WGI Due Dt": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="today"),
    }
)

# Specify start and end date in single variable.
date = ("2023-06-01", "2023-06-30")

# Iterate over each datetime series and check if values are between those in `date`.
keepers = (
    df.apply(lambda ser: ser.between(*date))
    # `any` will check if any of the values are True (same as using `|`).
    .any(axis="columns")
)

# Apply filter
out = df.loc[keepers]

print(out.head())

     EOD (HIRE_DT) Grade Entry Date  Step Date WGI Due Dt
1247    2023-06-01       2023-06-01 2023-06-01 2023-06-01
1248    2023-06-02       2023-06-02 2023-06-02 2023-06-02
1249    2023-06-03       2023-06-03 2023-06-03 2023-06-03
1250    2023-06-04       2023-06-04 2023-06-04 2023-06-04
1251    2023-06-05       2023-06-05 2023-06-05 2023-06-05


Thanks - I stole part of that and it worked. Can you tell me why you need the * in front of date?

@NKME * unpacks the items in date -> equivalent to ser.between(date[0], ..., date[N]). Since date only has two items, we supply args to the first two parameters in pandas.Series.between. Additional resources: What do ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) mean in a function call? and Python unpacking operator (*)
